# How to set class path in Config.ini file of a eclispe RCP product using -vm argument in linux

Tags: java, linux, jvm, eclipse-rcp, classpath

In my eclipse RCP product, I am bundling my JRE and  am point to it by -vm argument in config.ini file. JRE is loading properly and it is working fine for me in windows.

I need to do the same in Linux also. But when I tried with -vm ./jdk/jre/bin
option, I am getting an error saying couldn't locate JVM.

Any one please help me to set the class path in Linux for Java using -vm argument?

Comment: Don't use './' since that is relative to the current directory, use the full path to the jdk.

Answer (score 0):

1. First method is as following:
   1)Open the file /etc/profile with an editor 
   2)Add following context at the end of /etc/profile： 
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/share/jdk1.6.0_14 
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH 
   export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar 
   3) Login again.
2. the second method is much safer:
   1) Open .bash_profile file with some editors under the folder usr
   2) Append following context to the end of .bash_profile：

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/share/jdk1.6.0_14 
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH 
   export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
   ```

3) Login again